# "Работникам, получающим оклады" - это причастный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация

> Каждый час оплачивается: работникам с повременной оплатой труда, а также получающим должностные оклады(,) - не ниже двойных ставок.

Нужна ли здесь запятая? Здесь это как причастный оборот?

Comment: "не ниже двойных ставок" входит в причастный оборот. Вторая запятая не нужна. 

Comment: Нет. Это относится к "оплате", в оборот не входит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, здесь логично трактовать как причастный оборот

Но вопрос о том, сохранять ли запятую при встрече её с тире оcтаётся предметом дискуссий.
Единых и всеобъемлющих правил нет. Но в данном случае я бы однозначно её оставил, иначе будет восприниматься как "получающим оклады не ниже двойных ставок".

А нельзя фразу переделать? Любая перестановка составляющих снимет все вопросы.

*Работникам с повременной оплатой труда, а также получающим должностные оклады, каждый час оплачивается не ниже двойных ставок.*

Comment: Да, думаю, перестановка упростит предложение. Спасибо :)